# Populate date in MultiOptions element of Zend Form

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

Hello I have an array like this :

```
Array ( 
  [id] => 1 
  [code] => Dep98 
  [description] => Hello World 
  [facility] => Array ( 
    [0] => FacName1 
    [1] => FacName2
  )
)
```

But when I populate this array to Zend_Form it only show data in textboxes elements having same id as defined in array index not in multiselect dropdown element. for example:

```
'code'        id is also define in form's first textbox element,
'description' id is also define in form's second textbox element,
'facility'    id is also define in form's third MultiOptions element
```

But in MultiOptions it does not show any record.

Comment: Could you possibly show the code you are using for the element creation/population?

Answer (score 1):

What exactly do you want in the drop down box?

The array you pass to multiOptions must be in the form of value => title.

You may want to loop through your results and generate an options array.

For example

```
$options = array();
foreach ( $data as $value ) {    
  $options[$value['id']] = $value['description'];
}

$select = Zend_From_Element_Select("select_field");
$select->multiOptions($options);
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Travis, you should pass an array with following values to populate:

```
$vals = array('code'=>5, 
              'description' => 'testing', 
              'facility' => array(1=>'FacName2'));
$form->populate($vals);
```

But note this - **options must be filled** in the facility form element **before attempting to populate or validate**, dont expect facility value to be set if there is an empty list of options in the facility element.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

> Array (
>
> > [id] => 1
> >       [code] => Dep98
> >       [description] => Hello World
> >       [facility] => Array (
> >         FacName1 => [0]
> >         FacName2 => [1]
> >     )
> >     )